# Unable to make thinkfan work - ERROR: /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input: No such file or directory

Tags: thinkpad, temperature, sensors, thinkfan

I followed several guides to setup Thinkfan on my Thinkpad T420 as well as I could but I am still not able to get it working.

**Error**

```
$ sudo thinkfan -n
ERROR: /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input: No such file or directory
```

**Configs**

```
thinkfan/hirsute,now 1.2.1-2 amd64 [installed]
lm-sensors/hirsute,now 1:3.6.0-7 amd64 [installed]
```

```
$ sensors
thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        3575 RPM

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          12.44 V  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +57.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +55.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +56.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +55.0°C  (crit = +98.0°C)
```

```
$ cat /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf 
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.


# Generated by sensors-detect on Fri May 14 08:59:44 2021
# Chip drivers
coretemp

# Generated by sensors-detect on Fri May 14 22:52:42 2021
# Chip drivers
coretemp
```

```
$ cat /etc/thinkfan.conf
sensor /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon3/temp3_input
sensor /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon3/temp1_input
sensor /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon3/temp2_input
sensor /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/hwmon1/temp1_input

(0,     0,      42)
(1,     40,     47)
(2,     45,     52)
(3,     50,     57)
(4,     55,     62)
(5,     60,     67)
(6,     65,     72)
(7,     70,     77)
(127,   75,     32767)
```

```
$ find /sys/devices -type f -name "temp*_input"
/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon3/temp3_input
/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon3/temp1_input
/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon3/temp2_input
/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/hwmon1/temp1_input
```

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan.conf
options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1
```

```
$ cat /etc/default/thinkfan
# Additional startup parameters
#DAEMON_ARGS="-q"
START=yes
DAEMON_ARGS="-q -b 1 -s 3"
```

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 21.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.21.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.80.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.11.0-17-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i7-2620M CPU @ 2.70GHz
Memory: 7.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa DRI Intel® HD Graphics 3000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After update to ubuntu 21.04,i got the same problem, then i add this line to `/etc/default/thinkfan`, my problem is ok.

```
THINKFAN_ARGS="-c /etc/thinkfan.conf"
```

Comment: Thanks that was it. I should have thought of that. I wasn't able to run `thinkfan -n` but I was able to run `thinkfan -c /etc/thinkfan.conf`. I also saw in the system status that that it needed `DAEMON_ARGS` and `THINKFAN_ARGS` but I wasn't sure about the latter or where to put it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Not sure why folks downvoted a well formed post. Please do up vote for visibility.